# Countdown js with action at the end

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a countdown with js and when the countdown is done an element which is hidden during the countdown needs to be visible.

I've got so far but can't seem to figure out why the element `.homepage_search` doesn't become visible.

```
     function timer(time,update,complete) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var now = time-(new Date().getTime()-start);
        if( now <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            complete();
        }
        else update(Math.floor(now/1000));
    },100); 
}

    timer(
        6000,
        function(timeleft) { 
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timeleft;
        },
        function() { // what to do after
            $('.homepage_search').css({"visibility":"visible"});
        }
    );
```

Comment: Does the element become visible when you set the css manually?

Comment: for me it's working https://jsfiddle.net/08wdn6q4/

Comment: Yes. I have .hompage_search {visibility: hidden;}. When I manually change it to 'visible' it shows.

Comment: strange....It doesn't work for me

Comment: Och!!!! Had the wrong selector...stupid me!